# How to print data to Panel Pane in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to send data to a Panel Pane.

I have a simple .tpl file that for now just prints a message:

```
<?php print $message; ?>
```

However, I am having trouble sending the message data to this .tpl. The above print returns nothing.

On my .module file I have:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ctools_plugin_directory().
 */
function message_ctools_plugin_directory($owner, $plugin_type) {
  if (($owner === 'ctools' && !empty($plugin_type)) || ($owner === 'panels' && $plugin_type === 'styles')) {
    return "plugins/$plugin_type";
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function message_theme() {
  return [
    'message_base' => [
      'template' => 'theme/message',
      'variables' => [
        'message' => '',
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

And on the panel .inc file I have:

```
function message_panel_render($subtype, $conf, $args, $contexts) {
  $block = new stdClass();

  $config = default_settings();

  $block->content = [
    '#theme' => 'message_base',
    'message' => filter_xss($config['message']),
  ];

  return $block;
}
```

When I `dpm($block);` within the above function I see all is correct. It's just nothing seems to reach the .tpl file.

Would anyone know what I've done wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Found it worked with a `#` at `'#message' => filter_xss($config['message']),`